# Laravel - Job dispatched on one server, handled on another

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs, supervisord

I'm working on the logging aspect of a Laravel application, amd was planning to send the data to an SQS for retrieval at a later time.  However, I would like to dispatch the job from my production server to the AWS Queue, but then have a Queue working on a separate Logging server which listens to the Queue.

I understand how to setup the Queue worker to listen to the Queue, however, Laravel's Jobs are self handling.  So when the worker on the Logging server retrieves the message from SQS, it will look for a job at the same namespace (with the same Class name) to handle it. Is there any way to handle this differently, or do I just simply need to name the Job Handler on the Logging server, the same as the Job Dispatcher on the Production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create different queues for each specific server and send each Job on one of them depending on where they have to be executed.

Basically, this is how to push a job on a specific queue:

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->onQueue('emails');
```

And here is the command to process jobs from a specific queue:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=emails
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, i understand that part.  It's the handling of the job on the logging server that im wondering about.  Per your email, it seems that if my production code had a Job called `SendReminderEmail`, then my logging server (which is running the Queue) would need a Job called `SendReminderEmail` so that it is implicitly handled.  Is that accurate?

Comment: Basically, laravel serialize the Job object before pushing to the queue provider, then on the other end, it recreate the original object using the serialized data and the class definition. So yes it need to have the exact same class on both servers.

Comment: I see.  That seems unfortunate.  How do people usually handle this?  I wouldn't want to duplicate the entire production repo on the logging server, as they would be tons of unnecessary bloat.

Comment: We handle this by not using laravels queues. We use RabbitMQ And set up our own queues and message bus that don'r rely on a serialised instance of a class that doesn't exist in our other applications.

Comment: @Atrakeur do you still use this solution? In my case, it works well when I use RabbitMQ, but doesn't work when I use Redis as a connection. Redis works well when I'm pushing in the same repo. In Redis, I found only `["1"]` in the `value` field. There is no payload. Thank you.

Comment: @Atrakeur Seems like an issue with a Redis prefix. Need to dig more.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar challenge. Since we use docker containers for our application we defined a dedicated *worker service* which shares a volume with the web app. This worker service uses a very simple image with supervisord to consume the jobs that are pushed by the web app. This way we can share the job classes between both services with the possiblity of individually scaling the worker service.

Here's a sample of the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: ${AWS_ACC}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx-php:1.0
    env_file:
      - "env.list.${APP_ENV}"
    ports:
     - 80:80
     - 443:443
    tty: true
    volumes:
     - ${PWD}:/var/www/html

  worker:
    image: ${AWS_ACC}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/php-worker:1.0
    env_file:
      - "env.list.${APP_ENV}"
    tty: true
    volumes:
     - ${PWD}:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - web
...
```

Another potential solution I had in mind was to use git submodules to share the job classes between two projects. Since laravel simply serializes the Job classes, as long as they match signatures, it should work.